# Django: identify app in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have three apps in my Django project that correspond to separate parts of the website. All three parts are accessible from the navigation menu, defined in common base.html template.

I want to be able to identify the app that called the template to add an 'active' css class to the menu option corresponding to the active part of the site.

What's the best way to do it, short of modifying each view to pass an additional variable to the template?

Comment: Can't you do this using javascript?

Comment: I don't want to rely on javascript to achieve something that can be achieved server-side, simpler and less error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most non-invasive way would be:

1. Write a template tag that generates your menu.
2. Update your context with the application name.
3. Pass this to the template tag and modify the css accordingly.

I'll explain the second bit, as writing [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) is covered in detail in the django documentation.

To update the context; we need some middleware. This *should* do what you need:

```
class SetApplicationName(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        request.current_app = view_func.__module__.split('.')[0]
```

Place this somewhere django can find it (in any directory in `PYTHONPATH`), and add it to your middleware classes. Also, make sure you have `django.core.context_processors.request` in your template context processors.

In your templates, now you have `{{ request.current_app }}` which should point the app name.

Your template tag should be something like `{% navigation_menu request.current_app %}`, and you can then modify your menu css accordingly.

Comment: +1 for middleware, but it would process everywhere on the project. About custom tag: it will do a work, which could be done without additional tag.

Comment: If you don't want to change every view method; middleware is the way to go.

Comment: There may be some views, that may not render templates with navigation bar. But middleware will still process.

Comment: Thanks, does the trick. Just for clarification, I can access the variable in templates as `{{ request.current_app }}`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try "overriding" the {%block%} tag.

In your base.html template put something like:

```
{%block navigation_bar%}
 <div class="regular">First app</div>
 <div class="regular">Second app</div>
 <div class="regular">Third app</div>
{%endblock%}
```

In your descendant templates, change that navitation_bar block with other. first_app_base.html looks like:

```
{%extends "base.html"%}

{%block navigation_bar%}
 <div class="active">First app</div>
 <div class="regular">Second app</div>
 <div class="regular">Third app</div>
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: Thing is it's not very dry. Modifying the menu would require changing it in all children templates. Thanks though.

Comment: You could DRY it a little using one block per entry. I think it's the recommended in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/templates/#template-inheritance, adding a lot of {%blocks%}, explicitly: "If you find yourself duplicating content in a number of templates, it probably means you should move that content to a {% block %} in a parent template."

Answer (score 0):

If you define navigation menu in separate template, you could [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#include) it with additional context.

**base.html:**

```
{% block navigation %}Here will be navigation{% endblock %}
```

**template_from_some_app.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block navigation %}
    {% include "navigation.html" with active_app='second_app' %}
{% endblock %}
```

**navigation.html:**

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li {% if active_app == 'first_app' %} class="active">{% endif %}>
        First app
    </li>
    <li {% if active_app == 'second_app' %} class="active">{% endif %}>
        Second app
    </li>
    <li {% if active_app == 'third_app' %} class="active">{% endif %}>
        Third app
    </li>
</ul>
```